# Primitive Roots and Order

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, primitive-roots

Determine ord$_{17}2^{12}$.

Below is what I think the answer is. Any comments and suggestions on how to approach the problem would be great!

So does this mean that:

Since,

$ 2^{12} \equiv (2^6)^2\equiv (13)^2\equiv  169 \equiv 16$ (mod $17$).

Hence, ord$_{17}2^{12} = 16 $

Comment: You got that $2^{12}\equiv16\equiv-1$. What's the order of $-1$ (in presumably a multiplicative group)? Alternatively you could use the general result that if $g$ is of order $n$, then $g^k$ is of order $n/\gcd(n,k)$. Have you covered that result?

Comment: I think your reasoning is fine, but your conclusion is wrong.  
$2^{12}\equiv 16 \bmod{17}$ implies that the order of $2^{12}$ is the same as the order of $16$ mod $17$ and the order of $16$ is of course $2$ since $16 \equiv -1 \bmod{17}$

Comment: Also, since you're looking for comments (:-)), if you recognize that $2^4 = 16 \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$ you can simplify your computations a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2^{12}\equiv16\equiv-1\pmod{17}$, $(2^{12})^2\equiv1\pmod{17}$ and therefore $\operatorname{ord}_{17}2^{12}=2$.

Comment: Could you please explain why it goes from ord$_{17}2^{12}$ to finding the order of ord$_{17}2^{16}$?

Comment: @ivyblue It was a typo! Sorry. I Meant $2^{12}$ and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! After, thinking about it and going back and reading the definition of order I understand why it's 2.